# Publish App to App Store for Internal Use

Tags: ios, app-store, custom-application

I have published an internal app for our company's use, but it falls under Custom App. After the app status "ready for sale", then I realized that I had to get the redemption code and give to each user for them to install.

This is unexpected as I'm expecting to get a link and whoever go to the link, it will automatically select the redemption code for each ID.

I'm so confused right now. How could I publish the app to App Store and the app can be accessed by the public (like how we install Twitter, Facebook, etc.) even though the app is for internal use? I want the user to search the apps name at the App Store and installed directly from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a custom app, you really need to have devices managed by an MDM, otherwise distributing codes is difficult, as you have found out.

If you don't have MDM managed devices, an [unlisted app](https://developer.apple.com/support/unlisted-app-distribution/) is a possible solution.

Note that if your app has already been approved as a custom app you will need to create a new app record with a different bundle id for your unlisted app